# Validation of inputs according identical inputs value

Tags: jquery, validation, input

I have a form with  multiple email inputs
e.g

```
<input type="text" data-index="0" id="inputMail0" class="signup-input text-value" name="email[0]" placeholder="e.g. example@url.com">
<input type="text" data-index="1" id="inputMail1" class="signup-input text-value" name="email[1]" placeholder="e.g. example@url.com">
```

The user shouldn't insert the same email addresses multiple times.
The validation should be once the user click on submit button.

Comment: once you click on the submit button go through each email and you can generate a list of emails to compare them... add the code you have try to be able to help you more

Comment: Your question is merely an operating specification, a "gimme the codez", with no effort on your part whatsoever.

Comment: @  Sparky- if u don't want to help don't, but also don't write unnecessary comments! If I ask a question it's because I didn't succeed to implement what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9bwrd2ht/). I hope this solves your problem. I have not included Email Validation Code. You can paste the validation code where I have commented in JS. The following code compares values in input textbox.

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("input:text").removeClass("error");
        $("input:text").each(function () {
            var currentText = $(this).val();
            var mainElement = $(this);
            //Email Validation Function
            var allOtherEmail = $(this).nextAll("input:text");
            if (currentText.trim() != "") {
                allOtherEmail.each(function () {
                    if (currentText.trim() == $(this).val().trim()) {
                        mainElement.addClass("error");
                        $(this).addClass("error");
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                }
            });

        });
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" data-index="0" id="inputMail0" class="signup-input text-value" name="email[0]" placeholder="e.g. example@url.com">
<input type="text" data-index="1" id="inputMail1" class="signup-input text-value" name="email[1]" placeholder="e.g. example@url.com">
<input type="text" data-index="2" id="inputMail1" class="signup-input text-value" name="email[2]" placeholder="e.g. example@url.com">
<input type="text" data-index="3" id="inputMail1" class="signup-input text-value" name="email[3]" placeholder="e.g. example@url.com">
<input type="text" data-index="4" id="inputMail1" class="signup-input text-value" name="email[4]" placeholder="e.g. example@url.com">
<input type="text" data-index="5" id="inputMail1" class="signup-input text-value" name="email[5]" placeholder="e.g. example@url.com">
<input type="text" data-index="6" id="inputMail1" class="signup-input text-value" name="email[6]" placeholder="e.g. example@url.com">
<button>Click</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.error {
    background-color:#ccc;
}
```

Comment: @Sukanya- 10x. Do you think that a solution which insert the inputs to an array and use the indexOf() function will be shorter?

Comment: @saritrotshild Yes you are right. It will be shorter version of the code I have written.

Comment: @saritrotshild it depends on your requirement. If you want to just validate that there are unique email addresses then your array can be simple string array. But if you want to highlight the `html` where there are errors you have to make an object array keeping the elements to be highlighted or you have to make a 2-D array storing the unique IDs of the input as well as the value of that field.

Answer (score 0):

You can add following code to your page:

```
$(function() { //shorthand document.ready function
    function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
        var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
        return pattern.test(emailAddress);
    };
    $('#register_form').on('submit', function(e) { //use on if jQuery 1.7+
        var mail0 = $("#inputMail0").val();
        var mail1 = $("#inputMail1").val();
        console.log(mail0, mail1); // console log is best for debugging
        if (mail0 != mail1) {
            if (!isValidEmailAddress(mail0)) {
                // prevent form from submitting
                e.preventDefault();
                // inform user
                alert("You must enter a valid email addresses. Could not validate: " + mail0);
            } else {
                if (!isValidEmailAddress(mail1)) {
                    // prevent form from submitting
                    e.preventDefault();
                    // inform user
                    alert("You must enter a valid email addresses. Could not validate: " + mail1);
                } else {
                    // everything fine, do whatever here before posting
                    console.log("User has registered!",mail0,mail1);
                }
            }
        } else {
            // prevent form from submitting
            e.preventDefault();
            // inform user
            alert("You must enter unique email addresses. Please do not use the same email address twice.")
        }
    });
});
```

This will check that both addresses are unique. I also added a function for validation of email addresses which happens, if mail0 and mail1 are different. The trick is to call `e.preventDefault();` to stop the browser from actually posting the form. You can inform the user via alert or html injection, that there are corrections to be done. Using `alert()` as i did here, is actually not desirable in real site. For testing that is ok.

You can also [play around with a working solution here via JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hexereisoftware/L0jyzkpd/1/)